# how to iterate foreach into adata table

Tags: c#, sharepoint, data-binding, objectdatasource

im trying to iterate through multiple site URLs to get data which is returned in table form, the issue I have is that when I bind the datasource to gridview it overwrites the previous foreach, how can I have all that data written to one gridview? My code is below.
Thanks!

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            string url = item["SiteUrl"].ToString();

                            using (SPSite siteadd = new SPSite(url))
                            using (SPWeb webadd = siteadd.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                //
                                DataGrid grd = null;
                                grd = new DataGrid();

                                DataTable table = webadd.GetUsageData(Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageReportType.browser, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth);
                                if (table == null)
                                {

                                    //  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Table Null");

                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: You create a data row then add rows to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding the individual site datatble to the Datagrid , you should create another datatable outside the loop which will have data from all the indivial sites as below:

```
DataTable aggregatedTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                string url = item["SiteUrl"].ToString();

                using (SPSite siteadd = new SPSite(url))
                using (SPWeb webadd = siteadd.OpenWeb())
                {
                    //
                    DataGrid grd = null;
                    grd = new DataGrid();

                    DataTable table = webadd.GetUsageData(Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageReportType.browser, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth);
                    if (table == null)
                    {
                        //  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Table Null");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        aggregatedTable.Merge(table);//Append the data to previous site data.
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = aggregatedTable;//bind datatable with aggregated data
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the .DataSource to 'table' you should add the Rows from table to your .DataSource table.  This will result in an APPEND.

Answer (score 0):

You create a data row then add rows to it , something like below code

```
//This Section should be outside your loop 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col2", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col3", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col4", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
//End of section

//Inside your loop 
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr[0] = "coldata1";
dr[1] = "coldata2";
dr[2] = "coldata3";
dr[3] = "coldata4";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```